# WP + ACF How to retrieve data in front end product page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

As it said in the title I'm trying to retrieve the data from my ACF's fields.

Better than an explanation, please see the following screenshot:
[image]

So as you can see I've created under my attribute '*pa_size*' the 2 following text fields: **uk-size** and **us-size**.
Which is giving the following result in my Products->attributes backend:
[image]

Until there, everything's ok but the next step is to retrieve these data to the following single-product **(variable)** screen: 
[image]

I tried with [this documentation from ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) to do it but impossible. I also tried to place different part of code under */public_html/wp-content/themes/atelier-child/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php* but no way to figure it out. It's been days I am struggling on it and it's driving me super crazy.

I would like if I click on "UK" or "US" to display sizes like [on this link.](http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/26308/nike-air-zoom-talaria-mid-fk-premium)

If anyone could help even just a little bit, I would be really grateful!!

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide the code that you tried?

All of the objects that are not a post type use a special "post id syntax": https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

In your example you have the taxonomy pa_size, and let's pretend the term you are editing is number 352.

```
$term_id = 352;
$us_size = get_field( 'us_size', 'pa_size_' . $term_id, );
$uk_size = get_field( 'uk_size', 'pa_size_' . $term_id, );
```

Is this what you are looking for? Or are you wondering about tying it in to toggle the values of the dropdown menu?

Comment: Thanks, Radley I finally sort it out with a bit of your code and a loop on my $terms:
if(!empty($terms)){
 echo '<button class="accordion">Size Chart <i class="fa-sitemap"></i></button>
  <div class="panel">
   <table class="sf-table standard_bordered"><tbody><tr><td><strong>EU</strong></td>';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $eu_s = get_field('eu-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
     echo '<td>'. $eu_s .'</td>';
    }
}